# Setting priority on different resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, networking, resources

I'm setting up a website that imports multiple css files for multiple skins.
Is there a way to set a different priority on the stylesheets while loading the page.

I want the browser to first fetch the normal css, my js and all my pictures. After that, when the page is fully up-and-running, it can fetch my other, optionary, css stylesheets. (as these are triggered by a user declaring 'I now want to use the dark css')

An example to illustrate my situation:

```
<!-- CSS links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/transit.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/transit_dark.css"/>
```

Is there a way to let the dark stylesheet load AFTER my DOMContent has been rendered?

Comment: it is simple , you just need to put the line of code at end of the body .

Comment: You can declare stylesheet to be "alternate" but the browser may still load it normally. There is really no guaranteed, declarative way to set resource priority on the client-side except for scripts (with `async`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no purely declarative solution. What you can do is:

- insert the stylesheet just after initial page loading. Don't start with the "DOMContentLoaded" event because that's only the DOM. You may want to wait until the page's "load" event which indicates everything needed to render the page (including CSS and images) is already there.

  insert it as [rel="alternate stylesheet"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-is-an-alternative-stylesheet) so the browser won't apply it until selected.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var l = document.createElement("link")
    l.rel = "alternate stylesheet"
    l.href = "./css/transit_dark.css"
    l.title = "Transit: Dark" // a title is mandatory for alternates
    document.head.appendChild(l)
})
```

Using alternate stylesheet is semantically a very good way to do what you're doing, in addition to letting the browser preload all of them and offer a stylesheet selector in its own UI (Firefox does that out of the box).

Answer (score -2):

You could do this with javascript (jQuery):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="./css/transit_dark.css">');
)};
```